# How do I bubble up an error from the closure passed to regex::Regex::replace?

Tags: regex, error-handling, rust

I have a function which performs string replacement in-place via `regex::Regex::replace` via a closure which performs some operations on the `Captures`:

```rust
pub fn solve_dice_expression(expression: String) -> Result<i64, Box<dyn Error>> {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref PATTERN: Regex = Regex::new(r"(\d+)d(\d+)").expect("Problem compiling regex");
    }

    // For every match on the Dice expression regex, roll it in-place.
    let rolled_expression = PATTERN.replace(&expression, |caps: &Captures| {
        let diceroll_str = &caps.get(0).unwrap().as_str().to_string();
        let dice = Dice::from_string(&diceroll_str).unwrap();
        return format!("{}", roll_dice(&mut rng, &dice));
    });

    // Calculate the result
    let result = eval(&rolled_expression)?.as_int()?;

    return Ok(result);
}
```

I try to have errors bubble up by returning `Result<..., Box<dyn Error>>`, which mostly works via `?`. However, in the closure passed to `regex::Regex::replace`, I am not sure how to propagate any possible errors that could happen since it expects a closure returning a `String` and not a `Result`.

What would be the correct way to handle errors happening in that closure?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily.

What you can do is smuggle out the error in a mutable `Option`, then check that after the replacement is complete:

```
use regex::{Captures, Regex}; // 1.3.3
use std::borrow::Cow;

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

fn example<'s>(r: &Regex, s: &'s str) -> Result<Cow<'s, str>> {
    let mut error = None;

    let v = r.replace(s, |caps: &Captures| {
        // TODO: Optimize by checking if we had an error already and exit early

        let digits = caps.get(0).unwrap().as_str();

        // Uncomment to see the failure
        // let digits = "bad";

        match digits.parse::<i32>() {
            Ok(v) => Cow::Owned((v + 1).to_string()),
            Err(e) => {
                // Save the error somewhere
                error = Some(e);
                // We are going to discard the replacement,
                // so it doesn't matter what we return
                Cow::Borrowed("")
            }
        }
    });

    match error {
        Some(e) => Err(Box::new(e)),
        None => Ok(v),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r = Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap();
    let v = example(&r, "1");
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

You could also potentially implement the [`Replacer`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.4/regex/trait.Replacer.html) trait on your own type to streamline this and maybe slightly optimize it more.

Comment: This worked; I'll note that for my specific case, I did not end up having to stuff the error in a `Box` before returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I prefer:

```rust
pub fn solve_dice_expression(expression: String) -> Result<i64, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut error = None;
    let rolled_expression = PATTERN.replace(&expression, |caps: &Captures| {
        let result = (|| {
            let diceroll_str = &caps.get(0).unwrap().as_str().to_string();
            let dice = Dice::from_string(&diceroll_str)?;

            // you can use `expression?` syntax in this inner-func as much as you want
            let dice2 = Dice::from_string(&diceroll_str)?;
            let dice3 = Dice::from_string(&diceroll_str)?;
            let dice4 = Dice::from_string(&diceroll_str)?;

            return format!("{}", roll_dice(&mut rng, &dice));
        })();
        result.map_err(|err| error = Some(err)).unwrap_or_default()
    });
    if let Some(err) = error { return Err(err); }

    // Calculate the result
    let result = eval(&rolled_expression)?.as_int()?;

    return Ok(result);
}
```

The approach is similar to [Shepmaster's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60068572), except that it uses an inner closure that returns a `Result<T, E>`, such that you can use the `expression?` syntax in the inner closure as many times as you want, without the hassle of additional match blocks / error-storing lines.